# Why wasn't the diamond operator implemented when generics were introduced?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

With Java 7 they finally implemented the `diamond operator` which lets you omit the repetition on initialization when working with generics.

E.g. `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

This looks pretty convenient as it avoids writing "useless" code. It seems so useful that I'm curious why wasn't this implemented when generics were introduced.

Comment: they didn't do a lot of things. time and resource constraint.

Comment: And I'm curious why Java would take such a useless path instead of just omitting the duplication altogether as VB .NET and C# allow (var x = new ArrayList<string>() or Dim x As/= New ArrayList(Of String)

Comment: I don't think anyone here can answer this definitively unless they were on the committee that actually designed the Java programming language.  It's an interesting question, but I think that it can't be given a good answer without getting feedback from a very small set of people.

Comment: Because they didn't think of everything? Because people aren't perfect? Because hindsight is 20-20? I don't think there was a deliberate decision to omit it originally.

Comment: To my C++ eyes this looks threatening ;-) But is this really called an "operator" in Java? What does it operate on? I know Perl has a diamond operator, but there it actually does something. (I also just learned today that Java isn't standardized...)

Comment: No offense, but what's the question here? The diamond operator, in my mind, is simply syntactic sugar. Java has always been prone to repetition: e.g. `Integer i = new Integer(...)`. Do we need to say Integer twice?

Comment: @KerrekAB - It is not called "the diamond operator" in the JLS at all.  It is called "the diamond".  (Search the document!)  Unfortunately, you can't stop people from mislabeling things / inventing bogus terminology.

Answer (score 3):

It is a question similar to asking "why was the cordless ever developed? Why didn't we just develop the cell phone instead?". The answer is "necessity is the mother of invention". When generics were designed the necessity was to design a programming construct that did what generics so successfully did. Now the necessity was to maximize developer productivity, hence the invention of the diamond operator.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it